# How to put different music for different maps in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

i'm coding a game in python with pygame and i would like some help to be able to implement music (with my sound_manager function which comes from my sound class) in my game. the principle would be to put one music per map , and therefore to save the music as an element of the map (like the walls or the objects)

at the beginning I wanted to create a music variable in my map dataclass to be able to change it each time the map is created, but I'm a bit lost :/

here is my map class ( which allows me to create the maps) :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import pygame, pytmx, pyscroll
from Son import Son

@dataclass
class Portal:
    from_world: str
    origin_point: str
    target_world: str
    teleport_point: str


@dataclass
class Map:
    name: str
    walls: list[pygame.Rect]
    group: pyscroll.PyscrollGroup
    tmx_data: pytmx.TiledMap
    portail: list[Portal]



class MapManager:
    def __init__(self, screen, player):

        self.sound_manager = Son()
        self.maps = dict()  
        self.screen = screen 
        self.player = player  
        self.current_map = "CrapouliWolrd"

        self.register_map("CrapouliWolrd", portail=[
            Portal(from_world="CrapouliWolrd", origin_point="enter_house", target_world="Maison_perso", teleport_point="spawn_house" )
        ])
        self.register_map("Maison_perso", portail=[
            Portal(from_world="Maison_perso", origin_point="exit_house", target_world="CrapouliWolrd", teleport_point="spawn_sortie" )
        ])

        self.teleport_player("Player")

    def check_collisions(self):
       
        for Portal in self.get_map().portail:
            if Portal.from_world == self.current_map:
                point = self.get_object(Portal.origin_point)
                rect = pygame.Rect(point.x, point.y, point.width, point.height)

                if self.player.feet.colliderect(rect):
                    copy_portal = Portal
                    self.current_map = Portal.target_world
                    self.teleport_player(copy_portal.teleport_point)


       
        for sprite in self.get_group().sprites():
            if sprite.feet.collidelist(self.get_walls()) > -1:
                sprite.move_back()
    def teleport_player(self, name):
        point = self.get_object(name)
        self.player.position[0] = point.x
        self.player.position[1] = point.y
        self.player.save_location()

    def register_map(self, name, portail=[]):

        tmx_data = pytmx.util_pygame.load_pygame(
            f"../Map/{name}.tmx")  # PERMET DOUVRIR LA MAP SUIVANT SON NOM ! grace a f""
        map_data = pyscroll.data.TiledMapData(tmx_data)
        map_layer = pyscroll.orthographic.BufferedRenderer(map_data, self.screen.get_size())
        map_layer.zoom = 3

        self.sound_manager.play('MusiqueMaison')



       
        walls = []

        for obj in tmx_data.objects:
            if obj.type == "colision":
                walls.append(pygame.Rect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height))

       
        group = pyscroll.PyscrollGroup(map_layer=map_layer, default_layer=6)
        group.add(self.player)  # ici on instancie le joueur dans les calques

       

        self.maps[name] = Map(name, walls, group, tmx_data, portail,)

    def get_map(self): return self.maps[self.current_map]      

    def get_group(self): return self.get_map().group         
    def get_walls(self): return self.get_map().walls        

    def get_object(self, name): return self.get_map().tmx_data.get_object_by_name(name)

                                                                                # permet de rentrer simplement get_object pour faire allusion a un objet du decors

    def draw(self):
        self.get_group().draw(self.screen)
        self.get_group().center(self.player.rect.center)





    def update(self):
        self.get_group().update()
        self.check_collisions()
```

and here is my sound class with music methode

```
import pygame


class Son:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sounds = {
            'MusiqueMaison': pygame.mixer.Sound("../music/mercantile-the-legend-of-zelda-the-wind-waker-hd-ost.mp3"),
            'MusiquePlaine': pygame.mixer.Sound("../music/scandinavianz-nature-7504.mp3")

        }

    def play(self, name):
        self.sounds[name].play()
```

Comment: The `Son` class seems unnecessary. Add a `pygame.mixer.Sound` or just a `str` attribute to the Map class for storing the file reference if you want to have "one sound per map"

Comment: OKay , gonna try :) ty

Comment: Also, I assume you should only be calling `.play()` function inside of `draw()`

Comment: yes but the problem is that I don't know where to reference the music for each map. I instantiated a music:str in my Map class.
my register map method allows me to save the whole graphic part of the list of maps, but none of my methods allows me to enter music for a specific map

Comment: in other words, after creating music: srt in my class Map, I don't know what to do with it except referencing it in the part                                                                    
  self.maps[name] = Map(name, walls, group, tmx_data, portail, music=

Comment: How about adding a new parameter to register_map then move the strings there in MapManager?

Comment: self.register_map("CrapouliWolrd", portail=[
            Portal(from_world="CrapouliWolrd", origin_point="enter_house", target_world="Maison_perso", teleport_point="spawn_house" ,)],
            music=[Music(musicCarte="mercantile-the-legend-of-zelda-the-wind-waker-hd-ost.mp3")])

Comment: I created a new music list that I put in my register_map method. I can therefore fill in a music for each card, I only have to create play() method but I don't know how to create it

Comment: your comment allowed me to make good progress :) Thank you! I only have this last method left to do and I will have my music ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
self.register_map("CrapouliWolrd", portail=[
            Portal(from_world="CrapouliWolrd", origin_point="enter_house", target_world="Maison_perso", teleport_point="spawn_house")], 
            music="... path to your file... ")
```

Then pass through that music parameter down into the Map class constructor

Then add a str attribute to the Map class itself.

---

When you `draw` the map, you should create the actual mixer object and play it

```
pygame.mixer.Sound(self.get_map().music).play()
```

Keep in mind that you might need to stop the currently playing sound when switching between maps

Comment: it works ! but there is a problem! the music starts with big interference, as if you pressed play and stopped simultaneously. moreover my character is extremely slowed down because of this , 
there must be a loop somewhere

Comment: ok i got it !!!

Comment: I put pygame.mixer.Sound(self.get_map().music).play() in my "teleport player()" method because, def draw is indeed a loop which was causing the music to crash! now , I just have to stop the music when I teleport my self.

Comment: a method like : if self.teleport_player(name):  then stop the current music and restart it (the map changes, the current music also changes) and therefore by this means the old one would be stopped to give way to the new one